# Upload image via REST API /wp-json/wp/v2/media throws me out "Sorry, you are not allowed create a post as this user"

Tags: wordpress, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

please help me with this. I've created an app using React Native by consuming WP built-in and custom API's. So, there is one functionality which supposed to upload an image into media library in WP

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/media
```

. Though I'm the administrator and passing the correct token WP throwing me out:
"Sorry, you are not allowed create a post as this user". I'm using RNFetchBlob to Post the image.

The same works good in development server except in production server. But, they both are not the same configuration.

Any help is appreciated here.

Environment:

```
[Client]: Mobile Client
[Platform]: Android
[Language]: React native
[WP]: v5.4
[Authentication Method]: JWT Authentication
```

Comment: What is different in the configuration of the servers?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. My production server from bluehost with SSL, proxy. Development is http://localhost and rest all is same. Wordpress version is same across.

Comment: Can you upload through the wordpress dashboard or does that fail also?

Comment: Upload works through the dashboard with no issues. Also, I am able to create any post through REST using JWT token either. But, only facing on uploading image.

Comment: Hi @Filipe, thanks for your time. I resolved this issue. It was my mistake. I had set a wrong configuration in my .htaccess file.